# React, Como puedo consultar dos parámetros a la vez?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

tengo una duda. Desde una API traigo los datos de los usuarios los cuales son alrededor de 6. Como creo un array que solo contenga los datos de nombre y apellido? esto es para una barra de búsqueda donde me funciona al filtrar por los nombres pero no sé como consultar los nombres y apellidos a la vez.

Este es el header donde tengo la barra de búsqueda:

```
import UseFetchSearch from '../hooks/UseFetchSearch';
import UseFetchUser from '../hooks/UseFetchUser';

const Header = (props) => {

    const [search, setSearch] = useState('') 
    const { users } = UseFetchSearch();

    const searcher = e => {
        setSearch(e.target.value)
    }

    let results = []
    if (search === '') {
        results = []
    } else {
        results = users.filter((dato) =>
            dato.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())
        )
    }

    return (
        <header className='px-4 py-5 bg-white border-b'>

                                    <input type="text"
                                        value={search}
                                        onChange={searcher}
                                        className="block px-4 mb-1 py-2 pl-10 w-full text-sm rounded-full border border-blue-600 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500"
                                        placeholder="Buscar profesional" required />
                               

                                <div class="table-auto bg-white w-full shadow-xl" >
                                    <div className=''>
                                        {results.map((user) => (
                                            <div className='py-1 pl-2 hover:bg-blue-100 cursor-pointer' key={users.id}>
                                                <a href='/perfil'>{user.name}</a>
                                                <a href='/perfil' className='pl-1'>{user.surname}</a>
                                            </div>
                                        ))}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        
                   



        </header>
    )
}

export default Header
```

He intentado creando arreglos pero creo que lo estoy haciendo mal, les agradezco la ayuda

Comment: En el `filter` si quieres incluir las dos condiciones a la vez, usa  `(dato) => condicion1 || condicion2`. O bien si quieres que ambas se cumplan, usa `(dato) => condicion1 && condicion2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias al comentario de Jaime reformulé la sentencia y quedó de esta manera ocupando el operador || :

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import UseFetchSearch from '../hooks/UseFetchSearch';

const Header = (props) => {

    const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
    const { users } = UseFetchSearch();

    const handleFilter = (event) => {
        const searchWord = event.target.value
        const newFilter = users.filter((value) => {
            return value.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase()) || 
                   value.surname.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase());
        });

        if (searchWord === "") {
            setFilteredData([]);
        } else {
            setFilteredData(newFilter);
        }
    }

    return (
        <header className='px-4 py-5 bg-white border-b'>
            <div className='lg:flex lg:justify-between lg:items-center'>

                <div className="">
                    <a href="/"><img className="w-28 h-18" src="logosinletras.png" /></a>
                </div>

                <div className='flex gap-4 items-center'>

                    <div className='lg:w-72 h-10 flex flex-col items-center'>

                        <form className='w-full'>
                            <label className="mb-2 text-sm font-medium sr-only">Buscar</label>
                            <div className="relative">

                                <input type="text"
                                    onChange={handleFilter}
                                    className="block px-4 mb-1 py-2 pl-10 w-full text-sm rounded-full border border-blue-600 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500"
                                    placeholder="Buscar profesional" required />


                                {filteredData.length != 0 && (

                                    <div class="bg-white w-full h-fit overflow-hidden shadow-xl" >
                                        <div className=''>
                                            {filteredData.slice(0, 15).map((user) => (
                                                <div className='py-1 pl-2 hover:bg-blue-100 cursor-pointer' key={users.id}>
                                                    <a href='/perfil'>{user.name}</a>
                                                    <a href='/perfil' className='pl-1'>{user.surname}</a>
                                                </div>
                                            ))}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    
                </div>
            </div>

        </header>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Gracias por la ayuda!